# Find the Any method on an array of strings

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Given

```
string[] stringArray = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
```

then this returns true:

```
bool doesContain = stringArray.Any(s => "testa test2 testc".Contains(s));
```

My ultimate goal is to make a linq expression tree out of this. The question is how do I get the method info of `"Any"`?
The following doesn't work because it returns null.

```
MethodInfo info = typeof(string[]).GetMethod("Any", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Further explanation:

I am creating search functionality. I use EF and so far using linq expression trees works to create a dynamic lambda expression tree. In this case I have an array of strings from which any string should occur in a description field. The working lambda expression that goes into the `Where` clause is:

```
c => stringArray.Any(s => c.Description.Contains(s));
```

So, to make the body of the lambda expression I need a call to `"Any"`.

Final code:

Thanks to I4V's answer, creating this part of the expression tree now looks like this (and works):

```
//stringArray.Any(s => c.Description.Contains(s));
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(example.Description))
{
    string[] stringArray = example.Description.Split(' '); //split on spaces
    ParameterExpression stringExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");
    Expression[] argumentArray = new Expression[] { stringExpression };

    Expression containsExpression = Expression.Call(
        Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Description"),
        typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
        argumentArray);

    Expression lambda = Expression.Lambda(containsExpression, stringExpression);

    Expression descriptionExpression = Expression.Call(
        null,
        typeof(Enumerable)
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Any")
            .First(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string)),
        Expression.Constant(stringArray),
        lambda);}
```

And then `descriptionExpression` goes into a larger lambda expression tree.

Comment: `Any` is an extension method in the System.Linq namespace, which is why you can't find it on string

Comment: `Any()` is a static extension method belonging to the [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) and/or [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) classes (probably `Queryable` for your purposes)...but can you give some more information about why you need the `MethodInfo` for it?

Comment: To follow up on @JeremyTodd's statement: On a `string[]`, it'd be the `Enumerable` class's implementation, but with EF I'd expect it'd be `Queryable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var mi = typeof(Enumerable)
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == "Any")
            .First(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
```

And you can invoke it as:

```
var result = mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { "a", "b" }, 
                                           (Func<string, bool>)(x => x == "a") });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
// You cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable,
// but since you know you want to operate on strings, you can fill that in here:
Func<IEnumerable<string>, Func<string,bool>, bool> mi = Enumerable.Any;

mi.Invoke(new string[] { "a", "b" }, (Func<string,bool>)(x=>x=="a"))
```

And if you're working with Linq to Entities, you might want the IQueryable overload:

```
Func<IQueryable<string>, Expression<Func<string,bool>>, bool> mi = Queryable.Any;

mi.Invoke(new string[] { "a", "b" }.AsQueryable(), (Expression<Func<string,bool>>)(x=>x=="b"));
```